# Unable to save using Multiselect Item within ComboBox WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

Im creating an application using `Entity Framework` and `MVVM`. Within my app, I have a `combobox` that I have created following using [the following link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/)

Within this link, It is exactly what I want to achieve. Enable a user to select multiple items from a combobox. The image below will give you a better understanding of that I want to create.

[image: ComboBox]

So far so good. But within my application, I assign my `Properties` to the dataobjects within my `EntityFramework` entities to save data into the database.

VM constructor;

```
    public EmployeeViewModel(DataObjects.Employee e)
        : base("")
    {
        EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID;
        Title = e.Title;
        FirstName = e.FirstName;
        Surname = e.Surname;
        Position = e.Position;
     }
```

But like in the example web link, the type of which the combobox is bound to is as follows;

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _items;
public Dictionary<string, object> Items
    {
        get
        {
             return _items;
        }
        set
        {
             _items = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

So, if i do something like the following within my constructor, it produces the following error;

```
 Items = e.BenefitsProvided;
```

*Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'*

Which leads me to my question. How do I manage to assign the type `Dictionary<string, object>` to the type of which is in my Employee table called BenefitsProvided, which is a nvarchar? Is there a converter which could be used?

Any help or alternative methods to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your model correctly the property `BenefitsProvided` is a `string` that contains the various benefits of the employee as strings in a comma-separated list, like `"Voucher,Accomodation,Medical"`. In this case you can split the string into an array of substrings and create the dictionary with this array:

```cs
Items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string[] elements = e.BenefitsProvided.Split(',');
foreach (var element in elements)
    Items.Add(element, element);
```

Or in a more compact form using LINQ:

```cs
Items = e.BenefitsProvided.Split(',').ToDictionary(s => s, s => (object)s);
```

I was assuming here that both the `string` key and the `object` value of the dictionary are supposed to be the same text.